# get text from a child view in custom listadapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listadapter with an image and text at each level. I want to get the text of the selected level.

```
 public View updateView(View view, TreeNodeInfo<Long> treeNodeInfo) {
            final LinearLayout viewLayout = (LinearLayout) view; 
            final TextView descriptionView = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item);
            final ImageView img = (ImageView)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);




return viewLayout;  }
```

In my activity class i have a clicklistener on the list.

```
 customlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id){
                             //dostuff
                        }
                    });
```

> (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item);

returns only the text for the first item only and not any other selected item on the list.

How do i get the text of the selected item.??

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the underlying data used to bind the text to the text view, update that data, and notify the ListView that the data changed.

```
For example
List<Map<String,String> data = new List<Map<String,String>>();
// a bunch of add's

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Activity.this, data, R.layout.list_item, 
      new String{TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, IMG1}, 
      new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.IMG1});
// set adapter

// ...

onListItemClick(..., int position, long id){
Map<String,String> item = data.get(position);
   item.put(TEXT1, updatedText1String);
   item.put(TEXT2, updatedText2String);
   item.put(TEXT3, updatedText3String);
   listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: can you please provide an exmaple for that ...not sure abt what you said